# window object not exist but still exists in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

```
if(typeof window !== undefined) {
  console.log("this should print only if window object actually exists")
}
```

Can somebody tell me why NodeJS (0.6.5) is not working correctly when checking if window is not defined? If you call typeof window, you get undefined but still condition above fails to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Solved... Didn't realize that you actually had to put "undefined" instead of just plain old undefined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if(typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  console.log("this should print only if window object actually exists")
}
```

typeof returns a string

Comment: Interesting that it returns undefined and not a Reference Error, any idea why?